# Read from file inside an Adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

Im trying to use SharedPreferences to choose the app language. Since I have an external XML file with the translations, I can't simply use the default android studio's translator. My problem is that the InputStream line below don't works inside the Adapter (this Adapter puts the XML content inside the RecyclerView items). Basically openFileInput doesn't work and it doesn't show me getApplicationContext(), so I don't know how to solve this.

How can I read from the file inside the Adapter?

```
readFromFile(){
InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("language");
...
}
```

Comment: Where is the file stored? And is your `Adapter` an `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: You probably don't want to be loading a file inside an Adapter. You should be doing it when you create the dataset you're passing to the Adapter.

Comment: @MikeM. So I should use, for example, an AsyncTask?

Comment: Regardless of where you do it, any file IO should be done on a separate thread. My main point, though, was that you should handle the translations while you're creating the dataset - the List, or the array, or whatever - for the Adapter, not actually in the Adapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ArrayAdapter`, you can call `getContext()` to get the context associated with this array adapter. That is

```
readFromFile(){
    InputStream inputStream = getContext().openFileInput("language");
    ...
}
```

However, it is a **BAD** practice to read file in main thread. You should read the file in a background thread and process data in that thread. You can use a data structure to store the information in that file and pass the data structure to the `ArrayAdapter` for later use.

Comment: I can't use getContext(), andriod does not recognize it. The best practice here is to use, for example, an AsyncTask?

Comment: Yes it is better to use AsyncTask. So what is your `Adapter`?

Comment: I use my adapter to fill `cardview`s inside a `recyclerview` with content that's inside a XML file(for now it's on the internal phone's storage). I need this line because I can't get the sharedpreferences directly from the Adapter, so I write the language preference inside MainActivity and I read the language (i.e "french") inside the adapter.

Comment: I suggest you read the file in an `AsyncTask ` in `MainActivity ` and then pass the data to your adapter.

Comment: How should I do that? I only used AsyncTask once, in a very different situation. I tried out right after you post your comment but i can't figure it out.

Comment: Read the file in `doInBackground` and then pass the processed data to the adapter in `onPostExecute`.